# JOOQ create Table and insert values DSLContext

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I'm trying to generate a `Database` using `JOOQ`

i do create a Table with this code:

```
CreateTableAsStep<Record> table = create.createTable("TestTable");
CreateTableColumnStep step = table.column("testColumn", SQLDataType.Integer);
step.execute();
```

this works fine, but when it comes to inserting data, i run into a problem
the doc includes the following example:

```
create.insertInto(AUTHOR)
      .set(AUTHOR.ID, 100)
      .set(AUTHOR.FIRST_NAME, "Hermann")
      .set(AUTHOR.LAST_NAME, "Hesse")
      .newRecord()
      .set(AUTHOR.ID, 101)
      .set(AUTHOR.FIRST_NAME, "Alfred")
      .set(AUTHOR.LAST_NAME, "Döblin")
      .execute();
```

here `AUTHOR` is not a simple `String` it expects a `org.jooq.Table<R extends Record>`

i thought there might be a `return type` when creating the table, but i did not find it. Google did not help as `Table` is not the best word to search for ;-)

Question: how can i get to an instance of a `Table` - i do have its name as `String`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always create `Table` references via [`DSL.table(String)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#table-java.lang.String-) or [`DSL.table(Name)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#table-org.jooq.Name-). For example:

```java
// Assuming this:
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;

create.insertInto(table(name("TestTable")))
      .set(field(name("testColumn")), 1)
      .execute();
```

Notice also my usage of [`DSL.field(Name)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field-org.jooq.Name-).

#### Plain [`SQL`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/SQL.html) vs. [`Name`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Name.html) references

It's worth reading up on the difference between creating dynamic table / field objects at runtime either with plain SQL strings (as in [`DSL.table(String)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#table-java.lang.String-)) or with name references (as in [`DSL.table(Name)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#table-org.jooq.Name-)). Essentially:

- Plain SQL strings are case-insensitive and subject to SQL injection
- Name references are case-sensitive by default

In your case, as you probably created case sensitive table/column names, you should prefer the latter. More info can be found here:

- http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql
- http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/names